# How to consume activemq message asynchronously using JMS, and also maintain transaction?

Tags: java, asynchronous, spring-integration, dsl, spring-jms

How can I consume JMS message asynchronously(using task executor), also maintaining transaction? If any exception happens in messageHandler it should be rolled back and requeued in activemq.
Currently I am doing this, but it does not pick next message from queue until message handler consume message.(if any message takes lot of time, other messages in queue forced to wait..)

```
return IntegrtionFlows.from(Consumer.class, gatewayProxySpec -> gatewayProxySpec.beanName(gatewayBeanName))
.channel(Jms.pollableChannel(connectionFactory)
.destination(destinationQueue)
.jmsMessageConverter(jmsMessageConverter)
.sessionTransacted(true))
.handle(messageHandler, e->e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS).taskExecutor(consumerTaskExecutor).maxMessagesPerPoll(10).transactional(transactionManager()))).get()
```

I also tried this, which is truly asynchronous but since it breaks transaction boundaries, it's of no use for my use case.

```
return IntegrtionFlows.from(Consumer.class, gatewayProxySpec -> gatewayProxySpec.beanName(gatewayBeanName))
.channel(Jms.channel(connectionFactory)
.destination(destinationQueue)
.jmsMessageConverter(jmsMessageConverter))
.channel(MessageChannels.executor(consumerTaskExecutor))
.handle(messageHandler)
.get()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirements I would really stay away from `MessageChannels.executor()` and even `Jms.pollableChannel()`.

Just use that `Jms.channel()` and see its `concurrentConsumers()` option:

```
/**
 * Only applies if the {@link #containerType(Class)} is a
 * {@link org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer}
 * or a {@link org.springframework.jms.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer}.
 * @param concurrentConsumers the concurrentConsumers.
 * @return the current {@link JmsMessageChannelSpec}.
 * @see org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#setConcurrentConsumers(int)
 * @see org.springframework.jms.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer#setConcurrentConsumers(int)
 */
public S concurrentConsumers(int concurrentConsumers) {
```

By default it is one - exactly what you have explained with the behavior you see in your current solution.

So, just increase the number of concurrent consumers and you should see a different picture!